# Excel formula to create year range between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two input values for a start year and end year.  As an example 1997 and 2001 for the inputs.

I'm trying to create an output formula that creates a range of years between the start and end year inputted and adds a delimiter between each value of a |.

So the expected output for the above I want would be 1997|1998|1999|2000|2001.

Any ideas how to achieve this?  Ideally don't want to make use of any VBA, please.

Comment: Yes. Use `TEXTJOIN()` and depending on your version of Excel you can nest `SEQUENCE()` or a multiple `INDEX()` to create an array of years.

Comment: @JvdV - was going to suggest the same: `=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,SEQUENCE(1,Yr2-Yr1+1,Yr1))`

Comment: And if you want the date written in a given format, you could wrap the sequence in a text formula: `=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,TEXT(SEQUENCE(1,[YEAR2]-[YEAR1]+1;[YEAR1]);"DD.MM.YY"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,SEQUENCE(1,C2-A2+1,A2))
```

[image]